# In Rstudio read.xlsx function creates more columns filled with 'NA's and it should not

Tags: r, excel

I am working with a few Excel tables (.xlsx) and I would like to import my data into Rstudio for some following work.

```
mydata <- read.xlsx(file.choose(), 1)
```

This code above worked well until there came a single row which had 4 columns, 3 of them filled with NAs.

Then RStudio kinda created 3 more columns filled with NAs when I simply tried to display which has been read... So basically there are 7 columns, 3 of them is unnecessary.

I'd like to have only those 4 columns, with NAs in it as simple it was in Excel.

I tried to look for the arguments I can add to read.xlsx function and neither of them solved this problem.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Ps. a screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQPBG.jpg

Comment: does `skipEmptyCols = TRUE` doesn't work for you? like `mydata <- read.xlsx(file.choose(), 1,skipEmptyCols = TRUE) `

Comment: nope, it actually only puts one more coloumn filled with TRUEs hahaha.. :(

Comment: well and have you tried specifying directly the columns you want it to read using `cols`?

Comment: Usually when you read data into R and get lots of "blank" columns that means that the Excel document really has indicated that those cells have information in them, even if that information is "nothing". The simplest solution in my experience has typically been to either deleting the columns in Excel (even if they appear blank) or just ignoring them in R, since that's pretty trivial.

Comment: I have tried cols too, yes, as I've mentioned above ("I tried to look for the arguments I can add to read.xlsx function and neither of them solved this problem.").

Comment: And joran, I have deleted everything in Excel and it works perfectly for my other works but with one single NA in it, it puts a whole coloumn ... I only can ignore it, pretty  cool, lol. thank you for your answers, Aaron and joran.